# Format results of QUERY when passed an array in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Query to get all data from several sheets, and display them in a 'master' sheet. Each sheet has 5 columns, and all data is collected when I use this formula:

```
=Query({sheet1!A2:E,sheet2!A2:E,sheet3!A2:E}, "select *")
```

It returns sheet 2 beginning in F1.(Not A10 for example). Sheet 3 begins in K1. How can I get all the results to begin in the A column?

Here is a sample [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQ3y-PHj-11IFLHun4waWvYyAHCt_KGUikcIIsW2FTc/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Would it be possible to provide a sample spreadsheet (with editing rights) so we can take a closer look ?

Comment: Here is a similar doc. If you look on the DATAMERGE sheet, you can see all the data from the other three sheets all taking the same columns. 
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQ3y-PHj-11IFLHun4waWvYyAHCt_KGUikcIIsW2FTc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The array elements needed to separated by a semicolon(;) not a coma(,). The formula should look like this:

=Query({sheet1!A2:E;sheet2!A2:E;sheet3!A2:E}, "select *")